# How To Make Black-overlayed-image in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I wanna make the image has an black overlay and the title "Top 10 Australian beaches" won't be affected by the black overlayed image.

template.vue

```
<template>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="400"
  >
    <v-img
      class="white--text align-end"
      height="200px"
      src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
    >
      <v-card-title>Top 10 Australian beaches</v-card-title>
    </v-img>

    <v-card-subtitle class="pb-0">Number 10</v-card-subtitle>

    <v-card-text class="text--primary">
      <div>Whitehaven Beach</div>

      <div>Whitsunday Island, Whitsunday Islands</div>
    </v-card-text>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
        color="orange"
        text
      >
        Share
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn
        color="orange"
        text
      >
        Explore
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

The result of the code :

[image]

Comment: How exactly do you want it to look?

Comment: simply, adding dark background after the image and before the text a.k.a the text dont get affected by the overlayed dark background on the image @Daniel_Knights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can come up with two option:

1. Add a class to your `v-img` tag and style it using pseudo-elements:

   ```
    .your_class:before {
       content: "";
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
   ```
2. If your're using Vuetify version 2.3.0+ you can hack this problem with `gradient` property. All you need is to provide the same rgba color to `v-img` tag:

   gradient="rgba(100,100,100,.8), rgba(100,100,100,.8)"